# How can you make a treeview animate smoothly in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, treeview, css-animations, vue-transitions

My goal is described here in [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

If you toggle Child1.1 with the button then Child1.2 is transitioning smoothly to its next position whereas in the example below Child1.2 will jump immediately to its next position. How can you achieve animation to look like in the first case?

In the Vue SFC Playground you have the Comp1.vue which generates the tree but the wrong animation. The Comp.vue is showing the result which I want to achieve.